# Clicking the "review" tab when it's already active, refreshes the Review queue for some reason

Tags: bug, review-queues

Today I was mildly shocked to discover that clicking the "review" tab when it is already active, refreshes the Review page even though there is no visual indication (i.e. no hover cursor) that this should happen, and, in fact, it loads a different review task. This seems illogical.

I'm guessing that this is a bug?

[image]

This is also true of other tabs. For example, clicking the "Activity" tab on your profile when it is already active will also refresh the page.

Comment: Did anything ever come about from this? Just stumbled upon it :)

Comment: @I.TDelinquent Not that I know of

Comment: I currently can't test this as I've completed my review tasks for today. Will check this behaviour tomorrow :)

Comment: I can confirm that this is still happening on Chrome 75.0.3770.142. Looks like it loads a completely different review for me though.

Comment: @I.TDelinquent A different review task, not a task from a different review queue, right? If so, that's what I was seeing too, and looking over my question, I realize now I didn't mention that explicitly

Comment: yes apologies, that is what I meant :) Seems like a bug or UI issue to me. I had a similar UI issue a couple of weeks ago. It got more attention than this and it's still waiting for a fix... Hope someone from SO sees this though.

Comment: Personally, I like this feature, and there is reason to keep it. When you're in a review queue with no items and you need to refresh the queue to see if any items have been added, you can just press that button (sure I know I can press refresh instead, but I prefer pressing the tab)